# Maximize the system preferences window

Tags: system-settings, shortcuts-app

How do I maximize the system preferences window?
Specifically I am creating a Siri Shortcut to take a screenshot of the screen time window, extract the text from it and paste it in spreadsheet.
So, I would like to maximize the screen time window.
But there appears to be no option.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be resized.
It sizes to fit its contents and has no other option.

Comment: then what could be a way to extract the screen time data and paste it to spreadsheet, is this data stored in a file which I could access.

Comment: i've no idea, sorry. That would be an entirely different question, though.

Answer (score 1):

System Settings.app in macOS Ventura can be resized vertically (not horizontally).